# Can't understand the result of the high-order function invocation provided with not partially applied function as an argument

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, currying, partial-application

I have a high-order function declaration to apply a function given as an argument twice:

```
twice :: (a -> a) -> a -> a
twice f x = f (f x)
```

The confusion comes from this GHCi session:

```
*Main> let _4 = twice twice
*Main> let __4 = twice twice (*2)
*Main> let _16 = _4 _4
*Main> let __16 = _4 __4
*Main> _16 (*2) 2
231584178474632390847141970017375815706539969331281128078915168015826259279872
*Main> __16 2
131072
```

It is kinda clear with `__16`, because what's going on is just "multiplying" of this function call, so we'll actually get `(2 ^ 16) * 2` after it's invocation. As far as I can understood it happens because function given as a parameter is already partially applied, so the type of either __4 and __16 is `(Num a) => a -> a`.

But the result of invocation of `_16` with given function and integer arguments just leads me into confusion. I can understand that the type of either `_4` and `_16` are raw (are equal to `twice` function's signature, but are nested under the hood), but it gives me no clue about why the results differ so much. I just can't get program's semantics after providing a function that is not partially applied as an argument.
Can somebody please explain why is this number just SO GREAT?

Comment: Please do not use jpegs, formatted text only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at a reducing `__16 2` a bit:

```
__16 2 = _4 __4 2
       = (twice twice) (twice twice (*2)) 2
       = twice (twice (twice twice (*2)) 2
       = twice (twice (twice (twice (*2)) 2
```

compared to

```
_16 (*2) 2 = _4 _4 (*2) 2
           = (twice twice) (twice twice) (*2) 2
           = twice (twice (twice twice)) (*2) 2
```

Notice with the `__16` version, you are just directly doubling the number of times you apply `(*2)` with each `twice`. If you look carefully, you will see that the `_16` version is parenthesized slightly differently. You are first doubling *the doubling operation itself*, and then you are applying *that* to `(*2)` and `2`.

The first few steps of reducing `_16 (*2) 2` might look like this, following from above

```
     twice (twice (twice twice)) (*2) 2
   = twice (twice (\x -> twice (twice x))) (*2) 2
   = twice (\z -> (\x -> twice (twice x)) ((\y -> twice (twice y)) z)) (*2) 2
   = twice (\z -> (\x -> twice (twice x)) (twice (twice z))) (*2) 2
   = twice (\z -> twice (twice (twice (twice z)))) (*2) 2
   = (\z -> twice (twice (twice (twice z)))) ((\w -> twice (twice (twice (twice w)))) (*2)) 2
   = ((\z -> twice (twice (twice (twice z)))) (twice (twice (twice (twice (*2)))))) 2
   = twice (twice (twice (twice (twice (twice (twice (twice (*2)))))))) 2
   = ...
```

The innermost `twice (*2)` gives you two `(*2)`s. The next `twice` doubles that to 4 `(*2)`s, the one after that doubles that again to 8 `(*2)`s and so on. There are eight `twice`s in the above expression, so you end up with 2^8 = 256 `(*2)`s, so the result is `2 * (2^(2^8)) = 2 * (2^256) = 231584178474632390847141970017375815706539969331281128078915168015826259279872`.

Comment: Seems I've got it, finally. We'll get `twice^8`, which is equal to `16 times f(x)`, where `f = (*2)` and the argument is `2`.
Thanks! This description it clear enough for a newbie like me!

Comment: @AndreyIlyunin no, `16 times (*2) is (* (2^16)) = (* 65536)`

Comment: Oops, yes, messed up with numbers. From the last reducing step it is clear that `twice` will be applied at eight levels, so twice will be invoked `2^8` times. So with the argument we'll get `2^(2^8)` with a single `*2` added from the argument itself. Thus, we'll have `2^257`

Answer (score 2):

With Church numerals, the application of two numerals `a b` is equivalent to the exponential `b^a`. So, `_4 _4` corresponds to `4^4=256`, not `16`.

Roughly: `_4 f` means `f . f . f . f`, i.e. "doing `f` four times, or "multiplying `f` by four". So, `_4 _4 f` means "multiplying `f` by four, four times", hence `4^4`.

Indeed:

```
> 2^256 * 2 :: Integer
231584178474632390847141970017375815706539969331281128078915168015826259279872
```

Comment: I think I've get "what is going on", but not "why is it so"...
But thanks, that's the halfway!

Comment: @AndreyIlyunin It's not obvious at all. If you are a little confused, I think that's normal :)

Comment: Yes, it's kinda magical after imperative world with just cycles.

Answer (score 2):

#### `twice` isn't "twice", it's *"squared"* :

```
(^.) :: (a -> a) -> Int -> (a -> a)
(f^.n) x = foldr ($) x [f | _ <- [1..n]]   

((^.m) . (^.n)) f x = ((f^.n)^.m) x     
                  = foldr ($) x [f^.n | _ <- [1..m]]
                  = (f^.(m * n)) x
                  = (^.(m * n)) f x      

twice = (^.2)      -- f^.2 = f . f      f squared

_4   = twice twice
_4 f = (^.2) (^.2) f = ((^.2) . (^.2)) f = (f^.2)^.2 = f^.4    
_4   = (^.4)

       (^.3) (^.3) f = ((^.3) . (^.3) . (^.3)) f =
                     = ((^.3) . (^.3)) (f^.3)
                     =  (^.3) ((f^.3)^.3)
                     =   ((f^.3)^.3)^.3 = f^.(3*3*3) = f^.(3^3) = f^27 

       (^.4) (^.3) f = (((f^.3)^.3)^.3)^.3 = f^.(3*3*3*3) = f^.(3^4) = f^81
```

And in general,

```
       (^.m) (^.n) f = f^.(n^m)
```

Functional composition is multiplication, and application is (reverse) exponentiation.

Thus we have

```
_16 f x = _4 _4 f x = (^.4) (^.4) f x = (f^.(4^4)) x = (f^.256) x

_16 (*2) 2 = ((*2)^.256) 2 = (* (2^256)) 2 = 2^257

*Main> _16 (*2) 2
231584178474632390847141970017375815706539969331281128078915168015826259279872

*Main> 2^257
231584178474632390847141970017375815706539969331281128078915168015826259279872
```

Comment: the answer itself seems to be more complicated than the question :D

Comment: hmm. I thought it was illuminating. :)

Comment: I'm learning Haskell for about 3 days, and I've seen hell just now xD
I'll try to understand it... after a year of practicing, maybe :D

Comment: notice in `(^. m) (^. n) f = f ^. (n^m)` `n, m` are *regular* numbers. Are you familiar with operator sections?

Comment: I think that might be your difficulty here. Operator sections: `(+ 2) 3 == (3 +) 2 == (+) 3 2 = 3 + 2`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182714/discussion-between-will-ness-and-andrey-ilyunin).